# toolbar overlaps my button

Tags: javascript, html, css, node-webkit

I'm porting this app to node-webkit and I wanted to make my own toolbar + close button.  However, my knowledge of css/html is not that big, and I can't figure out how to make this work.

The problem is that my toolbar overlaps the close button thus making the button unusable.

CSS:

```
.toolbar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    background: #776e65;
    cursor: pointer; }

button {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
  background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
  background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
  background-color:#ededed;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
  border-top-left-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
  border-top-right-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
  text-indent:0;
  border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#777777;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:normal;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar">

<button id="close">x</button>
```

JS:

```
onload = function() {

  var closeNode = document.getElementById('close');
  if (closeNode) {
    closeNode.onclick = function() {
      window.close();
    };
  }
}
```

UPD: Code now works in the browser, but not inside node-webkit     `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` was also used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use z-index to position the button on top of the toolbar.

```
.toolbar {
    z-index:1;
}

button {
    z-index:2;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FLwT2/1/)**

Depending on whether or not you have other elements in the parent element, you may need to play with the z-index values to get them to show up how you want.  Just make sure that the button's z-index is larger than the toolbar's.

Comment: That kind of worked, it created an invisible area under toolbars right corner, that changes the cursor and if clicked closes the app. 
The button itself is invisible and not positioned as intended
The is in Node-Webkit btw

Here is the .nw file of the whole app just incase https://mega.co.nz/#!yMwSHTKI!ge-vbucFPEyz95xbdIT74mGy6IbljlfNODHr-3ISC-M

Comment: @Konata You might try a higher z-index for the button.  It works in the jsfiddle, so there is probably something else in your app adjusting this.

Comment: It works when i open the application in the browser, but when using node-webkit instance its just not there :(

Comment: @konata Sorry, I am not familiar enough with node-webkit to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your `<button>` inside of the toolbar or before it to force the button to have a higher z-index.

The other way is to give the `.toolbar` and `button` css definitions you've made an explicit `z-index` attribute, and make the button a higher index.

```
.toolbar {
  z-index: 10000;
}

button {
  z-index: 10001;
}
```

NOTE: styling `button` will apply to all buttons on the page, so you would be better off writing a new class for this button specificly or containing the selector like `.some-outer-element button`.

Answer (score 0):

use this and check..

```
.toolbar{
          width: 100%;
        height: 32px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-app-region: drag;
        background: #776e65;
        cursor: pointer; 
}

    button {
        float:right;
      -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
      -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
      box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
      background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
      background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
      background-color:#ededed;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
      border-top-left-radius:6px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
      border-top-right-radius:6px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
      border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
      border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
      border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
      display:inline-block;
      color:#777777;
      font-family:arial;
      font-size:15px;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-style:normal;
      height:30px;
      width:30px;
}
```

Comment: The code above breaks the toolbars spacing by like ~70px, and adds a scroll bar, still no button